# Problem with using UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiapplication

In my app I use this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let mainTabBarController =  UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? MainTabBarController
    mainTabBarController?.maximizePlayerDetails()
}
```

When I launce the app tapped by cell in Table, use some `func maximizePlayerDetails` from another class MainTabBarController, everything works fine. But when I signOut from app and then signIn again this method doesn't work(UIView doesn't appear). What's the problem?

Comment: You would need to show your `maximizePlayerDetails` method and if it is a method you would need `()` at the end of it.

Comment: put the breakpoint and debug, may be  after logout the rootViewController changed and not the type of MainTabBarController.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri , you are right  I forgot to add (), but have it in my code

Comment: @guru how can I check what rootViewController used after logout?

Comment: you can debug you code and put breakpoint and then print description of UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController to check what it returns after logout

Comment: @guru ok, I'll check it, thanks. How can I put the same rootViewController after logout in case if it will be the different

Comment: Simple UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = yourviewController